# Send email from Google Sheet when cell is certain value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is an example of the sheet I am trying to make this work for: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M79ki9QVRkfkwy1uWyNAVddeyPpcvqDppi3Et-b-cLw/edit?usp=sharing

The goal is that an email is sent when column I is greater than 2 and column K is null. Column I is a count formula based on columns C-H, which are manually filled in.

Here is the script I have, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
function sendEmail() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Workable");

  var listing_id = sheet.getRange("B:B").getValues();
  var flag_count = sheet.getRange("I:I").getValues();
  var action_type = sheet.getRange("K:K").getValues();

  var subject = 'New Listing Flagged';
  var message = 'Listing' + listing_id + 'has been flagged. Please resolve ASAP in the QA Google Sheet. Thank you!';
  var email_address = 'allyson@hipcamp.com';

  if (flag_count > 2 && action_type == ""){MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, message)}
}
```

What do I need to change to make it work?

Comment: You need to add a loop to iterate through the data values.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your latest code in the sample sheet. Since you've decided to use onEdit trigger, you need to use the [installable onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) because you are using `MailApp.sendEmail()` service which requires authorization.

### Pre-requisite (installable trigger):

[image]

[image]

---

### Sample Code:

```
function sendNotification1(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var startRow = 2;
  var startCol = 3; //Column C
  var endCol = 8; //Column H

  if(sheet.getName() == "Workable"
    && col >= startCol
    && col <=  endCol
    && row >= startRow
    && sheet.getRange(row,9).getValue() > 2 //flag_count column > 2
    && sheet.getRange(row,11).getValue() == "" //action column null
    )
  {
    var campground_id = sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue();
    var email = 'your@email.com';
    var subject = "New Listing Flagged for Fraud";
    var body = 'Campground ' + campground_id + ' has been flagged for fraud. Please resolve ASAP in the QA Google Sheet. Thank you!';
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
  }
 }
```

### What it does?

1. Your column I value depends on the value provided in column C-H. Hence your trigger should be the change in values done in column C-H (column index 3-8). I include an additional condition to check the current active sheet to verify that the modified cells are in sheet `Workable`. Check the value in column I if greater than 2. Lastly, check if column K is null/empty
2. Send the email

### Output:

[image]

[image]

### (Update)

Checkbox column included that will act as a checker button to trigger the email notification.

**Sample Code:**

```
function sendNotification(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var startRow = 2;

  if(sheet.getName() == "Workable"
    && col == 9
    && row >= startRow
    && sheet.getRange(row,9).isChecked()
    && sheet.getRange(row,10).getValue() > 2 //flag_count column > 2
    && sheet.getRange(row,12).getValue() == "" //action column null
    )
  {
    var campground_id = sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue();
    var email = 'your@email.com';
    var subject = "New Listing Flagged for Fraud";
    var body = 'Campground ' + campground_id + ' has been flagged for fraud. Please resolve ASAP in the QA Google Sheet. Thank you!';
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
  }
 }
```

**Sample Sheet:**

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues regarding the solution so I could update accordingly

Comment: thank you! I just updated with that code and tested it. it looks like the trigger may be causing the issue as the Error Rate keeps increasing as I try to test it. any idea on how to resolve that? error says: "Script function not found: sendEmail"

Comment: I did not encountered an error. Have you created the onEdit installable trigger successfully?. I just added the installable trigger then edit column c-h to trigger the count up to 3 and I received the mail successfully. Can you share the actual error message with its line number

Comment: resolved! I had not yet created the onEdit installable trigger, but doing that solved the issue.

follow up question, I received 3 emails regarding ID 83184, row 6. This row has a flag count of 5, so I'm assuming it sent an email when the flag was 3, 4, and 5 (as those other columns were edited). is there a way to update the script so it only sends once?

Comment: It is possible but you need to add another column (checkbox) and make that as the final trigger. Instead of modifying column c-h. Let me know if you need support on that

Comment: I updated the answer. See if this will fit your goal