# Trigger Google Apps Script function by onEdit checkbox in iOS

Tags: ios, google-apps-script

I have one single cell (A1) that contains a checkbox. I would like to get a scripted function to work onEdit only if the checkbox is checked (true).  How would I go about this?

I've tried all solutions I could find on SO, but unfortunately not one worked for me. The simple script:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {                                 
        headers : {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    }).getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + " " + date + ".pdf");

sheet_as_pdf_blob_document=response;

 
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("bunchofrandomcharacters");
  backupFile = folder.createFile(sheet_as_pdf_blob_document);

// Here we send the email

function sendReport() {
 
   var message = {
    to: recipient,
    subject: subject + " " + date,
    body: body,
    name: nameOfSender,
    attachments: [sheet_as_pdf_blob_document]
  }

   MailApp.sendEmail(message);
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and your question. Can I ask you about the current issue with your script and your goal?

Comment: Apologies if I'm not being clear. What I mean is how can I incorporate a way to automate this script for iOS by use of a checkbox in cell A1. My guess is through onEdit(e), but this runs the script any time a cell in the sheet is changed, and I would like to run it only if the checkbox is marked TRUE.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/68383732

Comment: How would the if statement look like for a particular cell, in this case A1?

I cannot find for the life of me find any thread that answers this question.. 


'onEdit(e)
If (A1 == true)' 

// send the mail triggered by marking the checkbox as true

function sendReport() {
 
doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Replace this with the name of the sheet containing the checkbox
  var checkboxCell = "A1"; 

  if (sheet.getName() !== sheetName) {
    return;
  }

  var editedRange = e.range;
  var editedCell = sheet.getRange(checkboxCell);

  if (editedRange.getA1Notation() === checkboxCell) {
    var checkboxValue = editedCell.getValue();

    if (checkboxValue) {
      //Here you can include the code you want to run if the checkbox is checked
    }
  }
}
```